# How do I display a manpage with groff in/on msysgit?

Tags: shell, windows, man, groff, msys

I've been unable to correctly set up a `MANPATH` environment variable in `msysgit` (1.9.0; 20140217) on Windows 7 (which is not my main concern here). Every time I execute the `man` command, I recieve the following errors:

1. /usr/local/lib/man.config: No such file or directory.
2. Warning: Cannot open local configuration file /usr/local/lib/man.config.
3. No manual page for {command}

As stated above, this is not a concern, merely an inconvenience as I know it's possible to use `groff [something] -T ascii /path/to/manpage` to display manpages. However, I am unable to find the command necessary to do so, having searched SE. (I know there was a question asking for it, but it doesn't show in my searches.) As a work-around, I've been using [online manpages](http://linux.die.net/man/), but I'd prefer not to search the Web every time I want to view a manpage.

So, first prize is the `groff` command for displaying man pages and the second is instructions on how to set up `man.config` (including file contents) for `msysgit`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
groff -man -Tascii < /path/to/manpage/without/gz | less
```

EG:

```
groff -man -Tascii < C:/Programs/msysgit/mingw/man/man1/gcc.1 | less
```

Note: Although switching shells is not needed here, `mysysgit` uses `sh` (not `bash`) as the default shell. Thanks to devnull for pointing thatr out.

Comment: So you could use `bash` when you were given the answer earlier.  Is it your habit to act in this manner?

Comment: I fail to understand what you're asking me. Is it my habit to tell somebody when the solution they provide doesn't work? Yes, it is.

Comment: (1) It's evident that all you needed to know was the `-man` option.  After learning that you realized that an answer is not useful for you.  (2) There is nothing in the command posted by you that would require `bash` and not work in `sh`.  (3) You should really consider providing enough information in your question: shell being used, format of `man` pages ...

Comment: 1. Yes, that's true. 2. Perhaps. 3. I didn't know these factors at the time of posting the question, so didn't include them.

Comment: `-Tutf8` is probably a more sensible default nowadays (instead of `-Tascii`)